# Unit testing custom TopShelf setup code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, service, tdd, topshelf

Within my solution I have added a TopShelf service. I have been writing some unit tests and attempting to mock up what is required to isolate the functionality I have written to setup this service.

So far, I have mocked up the `HostControl` interface `Start()` and `Stop()` functions, but when I run my unit tests to run the service, I get an `AbnormalExit` returned as the `TopshelfExitCode`.

I was wondering if anyone had an experience in this area and could point me in the correct direction of what else I would need to mock up or advice on the best way to achieve my testing requirements.

My test setup currently looks like this:

```
ServiceControlMock = new Mock<ServiceControl>();
ServiceControlMock.Setup(m => m.Start(It.IsAny<HostControl>())).Returns(true);
ServiceControlMock.Setup(m => m.Stop(It.IsAny<HostControl>())).Returns(true);

serviceExitCode = MyStaticServiceHost.RunService(ServiceControlMock.Object);
```

And I have the following test:

```
ServiceControlMock.Verify(m => m.Start(It.IsAny<HostControl>()), Times.Once);
Assert.AreEqual(TopshelfExitCode.Ok, serviceExitCode);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create your own fake instead of mocking here.

Create a ServiceControlFake implementing the required interface, but with your custom test implementation. Then you'll be able to see where it is called and what you can return.

If possible you may consider to reduce your ServiceControl interface to the minimal used function as well, it will simplify your fake implementation.

When understanding what happens, if the problem was trivial you may switch back to a mock. I personally prefer custom fakes when possible as they hide less behavior.

Hope it helps.